# CSS Max-height/width 100% is overflowing

Tags: html, css

I have images in a div, and some css to space everything out, but I'm having a problem where the main image is overflowing past the viewport (the image is cut off at the edge of the window) even though I have

```
img{max-height: 100%;
    max-width : 100%;}
```

currently, max-height: 100% fills the height, and max-width: 100% causes overflow (or vice-versa depending on the dimensions). I'd like it so that the image fills the width or height, whichever is smaller, first

See: <strike>http://jsfiddle.net/P32r8/</strike>
http://jsfiddle.net/P32r8/7/

Update: Images! It's currently doing the first one, I'd like it to do the second one.
[image: What it's doing]

[image: What I'd like it to do]

Comment: Are you trying to have the image start from the top left of the viewport?

Comment: Yes. My layout is left to right, the nav is on the left, the images (as in the fiddle) and then the main image. Everything is displaced using pixel margins, except the main image, which should take up the rest of the available space, if possible, without overflowing

Comment: So, top left of the viewport, after the nav and image list are taken into account

Answer (score 0):

I've added this code in the css:

```
div#image-space {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
div#content {
    float: left;
}
div#content img.clicked {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

and a container whitespace is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/P32r8/19/

Answer (score -1):

In your css you have written

3rd edit now hehe

i rewrote some parts most notably the removal of the `position:fixed;` in the `nav`
http://jsfiddle.net/CRjf7/

Comment: The problem with that is that I need the #content margin-left to keep my content from running into my navigation bar on the left side.
Also, I want the margin for each #content img to be 5px, so why would I change that?

Comment: looking at your new jsfiddle the clipping of the cat is caused by your overflow-x:auto;

Comment: currently, max-height: 100% fills the height, and max-width: 100% causes overflow. I'd like it so that the image fills the width or height, whichever is smaller

Comment: I see the changes to the code, but I don't see anything different in the output in terms of making the image fit in the space 100% on the larger edge

Comment: or smaller edge? The smaller edge of the viewport should be the maximum size of the image (for square images at least)

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

I had to redo most of the code in order for everything to work properly.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P32r8/30/

html:

```
<nav>
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div id="content">
    <div id="imagesContainer">
        <img id="1" src="http://placekitten.com/g/5000/" />
        <img id="2" src="http://placekitten.com/g/5000/?hello" />
        <img id="3" src="http://placekitten.com/g/5000/" />
        <img id="4" src="http://placekitten.com/g/5000/" />
        <img id="5" src="http://placekitten.com/g/5000/" />
        <img id="6" src="http://placekitten.com/g/5000/" />
        <img id="7" src="http://placekitten.com/g/5000/" />
    </div>
    <div id="loader">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding-left: 0;
    float: left;
    height: 99%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-right: solid;
}
nav ul {
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
}
nav li#current a {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 150px !important;
}
nav li#current a {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
nav li#home a {
    float: none;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    background-color: #BBB;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 6em;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin-top: -0px;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 230px;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:960px;
    width:55%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#imagesContainer{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-width:170px;
    width:37%;
}

#imagesContainer > img {
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
    /* Firefox 3.5+ */

}
div#content img.clicked {
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 210px !important;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

#loader {
    float:right;
    width:58%;
    max-width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid blue;
    position:relative;
}

#loader img {
    width:99%;  
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var loader = $('#loader'),
        imgDiv = $('#imagesContainer');

    loader.height(loader.parent().height()); // sets loader to parent height

    imgDiv.find('img').on('click', function() {
        var getSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        console.log(getSrc);
       loader.find('img').attr('src', getSrc);
    });


});
```

Comment: I'd like the image to scale up to either the max-width:100% or the max-height:100%, without overflowing. i.e. if max-height: 100% reaches the edges, the max-width flows past the edges, and I'd like it to not do that

Comment: Photos really help :), I updated the jsFiddle of my post. Let me know if that is what you were looking for.